# How do I test that an element has a `display: none` in React using Testing-Library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I recently start introducing some unit-testing in React using Testing Library and Jest and I'm looking to check if the css properties are working correctly. Not sure how should I check them with `expect`.

My test is expecting that an element will have a `display: none` and when hover a `display: block` and `color: hsl(0, 0%, 93%)`.

I tried to use `toHaveStyle` to check the style but my test is failing.

```
test('Card like-function is working correctly', async() => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<Card card={cardData}/>);

    const card = screen.getByRole('article', {name: 'card'});
    const like = screen.getByText('❤');
    expect(like).toHaveStyle('display: none');

    await user.hover(card);
    const likeHover = screen.getByText('❤');
    expect(like).toHaveStyle('display: block');
    expect(likeHover).toHaveStyle('color: hsl(0, 0%, 93%)');
})
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [@LinDu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463558/lin-du), this is a general question about testing elements display. I did add a code snippet to give more context, but the question is more about what is the correct/best practice.

Comment: Do all assertions fail or just the `display: none` one? Also, what is the message when it's failing?

Comment: [@Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14843551/avi), All assertions fail. The fail message I get is `expect(element).toHaveStyle()` and than in the next line `- Expected` and after that in the next line either `- color: rgb(0, 0, 0);`, `- display: none;` or `- display: block;`. Since I'm new to testing I wonder if I'm using the right syntax here.